# Execution of JavaScript without script tag in SAPUI5

Tags: html, google-chrome, sapui5

I am using the sap ui5. which loads and executes controller.js files and view.js files dynamically. But the thing is these javascript files are used without script tag. you can see in this picture.

[image]

Here you can see the HelloWorld.view.js
But there are no script in the html content. I just want to know how that file is added to the workspace (left side sources tab) and not linked with script tag. but strange it is working. we can put debugger on that JavaScript file also in developer mode. I am curious to know this for my clear understanding.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Helloworld view is loaded by UI5 dependency management system. Here it is loaded once you declare your view *sap.ui.view*. Internally there's a call to [jQuery.sap.require](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.require) that loads the view (a.k.a module). This is called [Modularization and Dependency Management](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/91/f23a736f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm) and it makes sure that the module is loaded only when it is required. In case the module is required multiple times, it's also loaded only one time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be found here:
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#L1739

Those other script files are loaded by AJAX requests as strings and then parsed/evaluated. But before parsing a new "line" is added at the end, with the 
`//# sourceUrl=...`
 directive. This makes the browser understand where the code was loaded from and display the code as if it were directly loaded from that URL..

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Debug_eval_sources for more details.